# "Contact us. Tap here." vs. "To contact us, please tap here."

Tags: usage

I am designing a "contact us" page and I'm wondering if "Contact us. Tap here." sounds natural.
Personally, I think it would be better to say "To contact us, please tap here.", but I'm really not sure about it.
Could anyone please explain to me if there's any nuance between the two sentences?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

These sentences use the imperative.  This is used for various forms of order, instruction or request. In the first the imperative "tap here" is modified by the infinitive phrase that gives the purpose. It is clear that if you don't intend to make contact, then you are not being told to tap.  The meaning is similar to "If you want to contact us, then you tap here".

The second pair of sentences are just straight orders.  The first tells you "You must contact us".  The second says "You must tap here."  I would understand these to be related. But this is still an order not an instruction.

It is quite common to see "Contact us" as a link text, as it is about the shortest text that could be understood.  I don't see any need to have "tap here"; we usually assume that users understand the basic "click to follow" interface of the www.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and patience! I have learned a lot from your answer. :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. If it's convenient for you, could you please tell me if there's any difference between "To contact us, please tap here." and "Tap here to contact us."?

Comment: Placing "to contact us" first gives it greater prominence and focus. There isn't much difference in meaning.

Comment: Obviously adding 'please' to an instruction makes it more 'polite', but I don't think people expect politeness in this kind of context, just simple instructions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your replies!